# dpkg --get-selections returning empty file

Tags: fedora, package-management, dpkg

I'am trying to use  dpkg --get-selections to get a list of packages, but it is returning empty file. I'am using fedora.

Comment: Why do you use ``dpkg `` on **rpm** based distro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dpkg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dpkg) is not a native Fedora/Enterprise Linux package management system.

You need to use the equivalent `yum` or `dnf` commands to accomplish your task. This may give you the info you are looking for:

```
yum list installed
```

or

```
dnf list installed
```